# Starting Django server with 2 different python versions installed

Tags: python, django

I am a Project Manager in a new position,  I need to install Django on my local machine to try and see how the workings of the language are constructed and maybe make a small web app to get familiar with it.

Problem is the current machine already had Python 2 on it so when I installed Python3 I now have 2 versions of python.  I have created a new Django project but when I run:

```
sudo python manage.py runserver
```

I go to localhost and all I get is errors refering to Django 1.5 and Python 2.  I am guessing its got to do with a versioning problem.  So what I did was run:

```
sudo python3 manage.py runserver
```

and I get the following returned to me alot of info on command terminal starting with:

```
Extracting in /tmp/tmpuaDHV8
Now working in /tmp/tmpuaDHV8/setuptools-12.2
Installing Setuptools
running install
Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to setuptools.egg-info/requires.txt
writing setuptools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to setuptools.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to setuptools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to setuptools.egg-info/entry_points.txt
```

and ending with:

```
copying setuptools.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying setuptools.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying setuptools.egg-info/zip-safe -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
creating dist
creating 'dist/setuptools-12.2-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing setuptools-12.2-py2.7.egg
Removing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.2-py2.7.egg
Copying setuptools-12.2-py2.7.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
setuptools 12.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools==12.2
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==12.2
```

Thing is it looks like all went well and I don't receive any Error messages, however, no server was actually started.

What can I do to get this up and running.  Seems to be taking way to much time for me to get this set up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be using a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to keep everything separate.

Comment: yea I have a virtual environment set up for the Django project I made and I installed Django 1.7 on there, but should I also be installing versions of python on there as well?, as well as running the server from there?

Comment: Yes, that's rather the point. The virtualenv has its own version of Python and once you "activate" it, you run everything under it to keep it separate from your local filesystem.

Comment: I see, however I didnt install python on the virtual environment I created.  all I did was pip install Django and the localhost error message is showing     Users/username/mysite2',
 '/Users/username/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.2-py2.7.egg',        ..    so would I jsut install Python 3 in that virtual machine,  also then how would I deal with Django calling the correct version of python?

Answer (score 4):

**for python3.4:**

EDIT: install python3-dev too:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

To make a virtualenv with default python version python3.4:

```
mkvirtualenv virtualenv_name -ppython3.4
```

*replace virtualenv_name with the name you want to give to your environment*

Then install pip for python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and then to install django after you activate your virtualenv:

```
pip3 install django
```

**for python2.7:**

```
mkvirtualenv virtualenv_name -ppython2.7
```

*replace virtualenv_name with the name you want to give to your environment*

Then install pip normaly:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

and once you activate your virtualenv:

```
pip install django
```

Comment: Im working on OSX,  cannot get python3-dev using brew, is there any other method?  Also, when I try to use the command  mkvirtualenv env_name --python3.4   I get the error  "Python: error: no such option: -p"

Comment: try this and tell me if it works: mkvirtualenv --python=python3_path myenv

Comment: I put in 'mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 firstpython'    get - Python: error: no such option: --python

Answer (score 0):

If you need concurrent versions the cleanest way to do it is to install virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper ([package source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper/3.4))

and have a dedicated local environment for the project.

Here are some instructions on how to set up that environment that will let you work on them in isolation.  http://railslide.io/virtualenvwrapper-python3.html

HTH

Comment: I tried to do this.  I am on OSX and when running the server I still get Django errors listing Python 2 as the directories

Comment: 2 notes: 1) don't use sudo when installing inside a virtualenv.  2) this link should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: Same thing as other comments, when I run the virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 <path/to/new/virtualenv/> command,  I get the following error "Python: error: no such option: -p"

Comment: what happens when you just type virtualenv --help ?   also "which virtualenv"?

Comment: its wierd I see it listed there:     --version    show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         Increase verbosity.
  -q, --quiet           Decrease verbosity.
  -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
                        The Python interpreter to use, e.g.,
                        --python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter
                        to create the new environment.  The default is the
                        interpreter that virtualenv was installed with
                        (/usr/bin/python)